# Output each match from sed as a separate file

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a file which contains questions with multiple choice answers.

The first line of each question begins with `010`.
The last line of each question begins with a lowercase `e`.

I need to output each match into a separate file.

```
sed -n '/010/,/e)/p' FileName
```

The above sed command displays the information I need. How could I output each match to its own file? The first file should be named `1` and increment by 1 for the next match.

Comment: You already know how to obtain the data you require so pipe this into a the [csplit](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/csplit-invocation.html) util to break it into separate files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sed can't do this, but awk can.

```
awk -v RS="010" 'NR > 1 {print RS $0 > (NR-1)}' filename
```

`RS` defined the Record Separator (normally a newline), and `NR` is the current record number. I add the `NR>1` condition because, since the file starts with the record separator, the first record will be the empty string before it.

Comment: `>` is the redirection operator: the line will be appended to the filename named on the right-hand side of `>`, and the file will be created if it does not exist. I'm using the value of `NR-1` as the filename.

Comment: thanks a lot, I was not aware of the use of `>` beside expr eval in awk. You opened my eyes.